# ¿Es correcto escribir "el Fisco", así con mayúscula?

Tags: ortografía, sustantivos, uso-de-mayúsculas

No hace mucho leí en [esta noticia](https://www.laopiniondemurcia.es/cartagena/2019/03/12/pillan-cargamento-droga-brasil-destino/1004011.html) lo siguiente:

> El **Fisco** brasileño interceptó la droga [...]
>   De acuerdo con el **Fisco**, se trata de la mayor cantidad [...]
>   Para la identificación de la droga los agentes del **Fisco** emplearon escáneres [...]

Como se puede observar, la palabra "Fisco" aparece escrita con mayúscula inicial en todos los casos.
Sin embargo, hasta donde yo sé, "fisco" es un sustantivo común, no un nombre propio:

> [**fisco**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Hzcd6wL)
>   Del lat. *fiscus*.
>
> 1. m. Erario, tesoro público.
> 2. m. Conjunto de los organismos públicos que se ocupan de la recaudación de impuestos.
> 3. m. Moneda de cobre de Venezuela, que equivalía a la cuarta parte de un centavo.

El uso en medios no es unánime: [la mayoría parecen usar "fisco", pero hay varios casos de "Fisco"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=%22el%20Fisco%22).

**¿Es correcto alguno de estos usos de "Fisco" con mayúscula inicial?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo sugeriría seguir lo que dice [el DPD con respecto al uso de mayúscula](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Hzcd6wL):

> **4.28.** Determinados nombres, cuando designan entidades o colectividades institucionales: *la Universidad, el Estado, el Ejército, el Reino, la Marina, la Judicatura, el Gobierno*.

Así, en este caso, `el Fisco` podría usar mayúscula en tanto se refiere a la colectividad institucional encargada de recaudar impuestos.

Answer (score 4):

Según la Fundéu (https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/fisco-con-minuscula-882/) debe escribirse con minúscula. No obstante, me llama la atención que parece circunscribirse a los ejemplos en cuestión:

> Por tanto, **en los ejemplos citados**, lo adecuado habría sido escribir «Las deudas con el fisco se han disparado de forma alarmante» y «Existe el temor de que el defraudador acabe esquivando el pago al fisco».

En tus ejemplos, @walen, "fisco" se asimila a "estado", y esto dice la Fundéu al respecto: https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/estado-uso-de-mayusculas-y-minusculas/

Mi opinión es que "Fisco" puede escribirse con mayúscula cuando es sinónimo de "Estado".